# Does latex2html convert equations in to mathml instead of images?

Tags: latex2html

I installed latex2html in my windows system. It converts the latex file into html.
All display equations are converted as svg images.
I need mathml code for the equations.
Is there any option to convert the equations into mathml code.

Comment: why not use a more modern system such as tex4ht or latexml, both of which can generate html+mathml tex4ht is included in texlive at least (not sure about miktex)